# Cannot read property [function] of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, undefined

I have this in my return part of my render function:

```
<table>
        <tbody>
          {nums.map(function(num, index){
            return <tr key={ index }>{num} <input type="submit" value="unmatch" onClick={this.unMatchButtonClicked} />
            </tr>;
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

But when I load the page I get an error saying: `Cannot read property 'unMatchButtonClicked' of undefined`

Even though it is the function directly before `render:function()`

```
unMatchButtonClicked: function(){
  console.log('called');
},
```

so what is the scope of `this` and why is it undefined?

Comment: set `this` for `.map` callback  - `nums.map(function(num, index){ /* code */ }, this)`

Comment: @AlexanderT. cheers bro

Comment: @AlexanderT. I have one issue with this though. it is now changing the `this` in other parts of the code and setting a variable elsewhere to be == to mouse click rather than the `this` it should be elsewhere. can elaborate if you need

Answer (score 0):

1. Option: `Array.map(function () {/*...*/}, this)`
2. Option: `var unMatchButtonClicked = this.unMatchButtonClicked` and `onClick={unMatchButtonClicked}`

Apart from that you should consider using an arrow-function for your click-handler or bind `this` to your function.
http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html